# how to properly build spark 2.0 from source, to include pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've just built spark 2.0 on Ubuntu host, using "sbt assembly".
Everything finished fine, but, when I attempted to submit a pyspark job:

```
bin/spark-submit --master spark://localhost:7077 examples/src/main/python/pi.py 1000
```

I got this error:

```
Failed to find Spark jars directory (/home/ubuntu/spark/spark-2.0.0/assembly/target/scala-2.10/jars).
You need to build Spark with the target "package" before running this program.
```

What should I do in order to re-build spark 2.0 to include pyspark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

1. [Install sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Setup.html)
2. Build:

   ```
   https://github.com/apache/spark.git
   cd spark
   git checkout v2.0.0
   sbt package
   ```